# Set an attribute for all instances of a class under conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

First of all, excuse my ignorance if this is a fairly easy question. What I would like to achieve is to create an attribute for every instance of the class (i.e. `filepath`), change it for an instance (i.e. in the first case, where I change the value of `filepath` for the `a` instance, but if I create a new instance, e.g. `b` I would like to keep the original `filepath` value.

```
filepath = '/path/to/original/file'

class A(object):


    @classmethod
    def _set_path(cls, filepath):
        cls.filepath = filepath
        return cls.filepath

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

A._set_path(filepath) # Set filepath for all instances: /path/to/original/file

a = A("Alice")
print(a.filepath)
a._set_path("/path/to/another/file") # Set filepath for instance a, but also for every new instance. This is what needs to be corrected.
print(a.filepath)

b = A("Bob")
print(b.filepath) # I would like to keep /path/to/original/file
```

Is there a way to improve this code and/or have a smart design pattern for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, correct me, if I did not understand what you're looking for correctly and I can adjust the answer accordingly, but from what I got, you're looking for a class and instance attributes and distinction between them:

```
class A:
    filepath = None
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

A.filepath = "/path/to/original/file"
a = A("Alice")
print(a.filepath)
a.filepath = "/path/to/another/file"
print(a.filepath)

b = A("Bob")
print(b.filepath)
```

Defining class `A` (note: in python 3 all classes are new-style which I presume is what inheritance from `object` was meant to be for as a hold out of python 2 habits) we define a class attribute `filepath`. This is strictly speaking not necessary, but if this is intended part of the interface... You could of course also specify the first initial default value directly in the class definition.

Then we assign our first value `'/path/to/original/file'` to it. At this point we create and instance `a` of class `A` and when we access its `filepath` attribute, we get value of the class attribute. Then we assign a different value to an instance attribute (`a.filepath`) and accessing it again we get its value back, while we have not modified class attribute `A.filepath` which is also what we see for newly created instance `b`.

Be ware though, mixing assignments to both class and instance attribute (of the same name could cause confusion and possibly unintended behavior. Consider this:

```
A.filepath = "/path/to/original/file"
a = A("Alice")
a.filepath = "/path/to/another/file"
b = A("Bob")  # b.filepath is "/path/to/original/file"
A.filepath = "/third/file"
c = A("Carl")
```

Now accessing `a.filepath` yields `"/path/to/another/file"`, but for both `b.filepath` and `c.filepath` are "/third/file" which may or may not be what we wanted esp. for `b.filepath` to be the case.

Hence for similar use case I would prefer something like:

```
class A:
    default_filepath = "/path/to/original/file"
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.filepath = self.default_filepath
        self.name = name

a = A("Alice")
a.filepath = "/path/to/another/file"
b = A("Bob")
A.default_filepath = "/third/file"
c = A("Carl")
```

Class has a `default_filepath` attributed which is used to assign to each instances `self.filepath` attribute. That should help reduce risk of mistakes. In the above example these:

```
a.filepath
b.filepath
c.filepath
```

Now have values of:

```
/path/to/another/file
/path/to/original/file
/third/file
```